# GROUP_CONCAT into unique columns

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I am using the query below and it is really close to what I need except that I need the GROUP_CONCAT sub-query to create unique columns rather than CSVs in one column.

```
SELECT answer, sa.exam_id, timestamp, sa.taking_id, te.source_url,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT answer)
FROM wp_watupro_student_answers as sa 
INNER JOIN wp_watupro_question as q 
ON sa.question_id = q.ID
INNER JOIN wp_watupro_taken_exams te
ON te.ID = sa.taking_id
GROUP BY sa.taking_id;
```

Any help is appreciated.

---edit---

Data and expected output are below:

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMMv7.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVgRk.png)

Comment: Show us your data and exepected output.  Off the top of my head, you might really be looking for a pivot query, which could require dynamic SQL.

Comment: Added the requested info above

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer, assuming that's available